# Is it possible to not show gridlines by default?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know that we could turn on or off gridlines for a given sheet here:

[image]

Does anyone know how to set this option by default for every newly created worksheet?

Comment: You don't say which version you are using so I can't suggest anything specific. But try to edit your default template to include the gridlines being enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Make the workbook to be like you want it: Gridlines, Margins, Footers, Headers Etc.
Then Save it as a Template called "book" (excel will add ".xltx").
Then move or make sure it is saved in excels XLSTART folder. Lately this is at "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART". For more info, I.e. how to specify a custom Startup folder, see https://exceljet.net/how-to-set-a-default-template-in-excel

Answer (score -1):

Go to: File, Options, Advanced. Scroll about 3/5's way down and un-click the Show Gridlines box.

Comment: That applies the same as changing it in the Ribbon - notice the sections in Excel's options dialog show that some options apply to the workbook or worksheet rather than globally.